# editing the random waypoint mobility matlab for a constant node

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Please help me out with this. This plot gives the mobile users that are moving. Now, I am trying to add a few constant points in the plot. Like the base stations for the mobile users '*'. I want to put say a '#' for every base station and put like around 10 of them.

```
function test_Animate(s_mobility,s_input,time_step)

v_t = 0:time_step:s_input.SIMULATION_TIME;

for nodeIndex = 1:s_mobility.NB_NODES
    %Simple interpolation (linear) to get the position, anytime.
    %Remember that "interp1" is the matlab function to use in order to
    %get nodes' position at any continuous time.
    vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x =  interp1(s_mobility.VS_NODE(nodeIndex).V_TIME,s_mobility.VS_NODE(nodeIndex).V_POSITION_X,v_t);
    vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y = interp1(s_mobility.VS_NODE(nodeIndex).V_TIME,s_mobility.VS_NODE(nodeIndex).V_POSITION_Y,v_t);

end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

figure;

hold on;

for nodeIndex = 1:s_mobility.NB_NODES
    vh_node_pos(nodeIndex) = plot(vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x(1),vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y(1),'*','color',[0.3 0.3 1]);
end
title(cat(2,'Simulation time (sec): ',num2str(s_mobility.SIMULATION_TIME)));
xlabel('X (meters)');
ylabel('Y (meters)');
title('Random Waypoint mobility');
ht = text(min(vs_node(1).v_x),max(vs_node(1).v_y),cat(2,'Time (sec) = 0'));
axis([min(vs_node(1).v_x) max(vs_node(1).v_x) min(vs_node(1).v_y) max(vs_node(1).v_y)]);
hold off;
for timeIndex = 1:length(v_t);
    t = v_t(timeIndex);
    set(ht,'String',cat(2,'Time (sec) = ',num2str(t,4)));
    for nodeIndex = 1:s_mobility.NB_NODES
                          set(vh_node_pos(nodeIndex),'XData',vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x(timeIndex),'YData',vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y(timeIndex));
    end

    drawnow;
  end
```

end

The complete submission of this can be got in the MATHworks site. 
http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30939-random-waypoint-mobility-model

Please help me out.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? Because the only reason your points are moving is that they're being changed with `set`, so there's nothing stopping you adding a set of fixed positions which you don't update.

Comment: Exactly, but where do I add the set? Because, I tried adding it in a few places and I observe the whole points not moving at all. Can you please tell me as to where I can add the set ?

Comment: You don't need to add `set` at all - `set` is only being used in the code to move the points. You need a second `plot` command which adds the fixed points.  I'll answer with a minimal plotting example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basic idea.  In the following, `fixed_x` and `fixed_y` are vectors of equal length giving the location of your fixed points.
`moving_x` and `moving_y` are matrices of size t x n where t is the number of time steps, and n the number of points.

```
%plot the fixed points
plot(fixed_x,fixed_y, 'p'); 
hold on
%plot the first set of moving points
h = plot(moving_x(1,:),moving_y(1,:),'r*');
```

Then, to move the points, we use the handle to the moving points, `h` to set `XData` and `YData` values. This would be within a loop where `n` is the time step:

```
set(h, 'XData',moving_x(n,:),'YData',moving_y(n,:));
%may need drawnow;
```

If you want to be able to see the points moving, you may need to add some `pause` command - otherwise it might cycle through the update loop so quickly you won't see anything except the final set of positions.  On the other hand, you could just save out the figure as an image file after you've moved the points with `set`, or add it as a frame to a movie, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Its working like a charm ! I have 2 doubts now. 1) Suppose, If I have to add more than one fixed point. The above only allows for one fixed point. Please help.                          2 ) For tracking the x  and y coordinates of the node, I am using  vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x(timeIndex) and vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y(timeIndex). I put an if else in the innermost for loop, for checking whether the values are in the limits or not, the else case is not getting executed at all. Do I have to take the values from elsewhere ? Please help me out.

Comment: `fixed_x,fixed_y` can contain more than one point - you just need to make sure they're the same length and that the linestyle format (in this case `p`) is something that plots a marker and not a line.  For the other, I don't know what sort of `else` case you've set up or why you need to check limits as you go, so can't comment but you will make your life easier by not using structs here.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both are working just perfect. On this, I tried to overlay a polar plot on this plot, I am able to achieve it along with the animation of nodes. But I have to put more than one such plot. Got the polar plot with these equations.                                       theta= 0:pi/1000:5*pi;
en=cos(pi/2.*cos(theta)).*cos(pi.*cos(theta));
polar(theta,en);                                                      I want to put some 4 or 5 of these polar plots on the same plot which has the moving nodes. Plot can be in random/fixed place. Request  really big help.

Comment: I could overlay with these commands.                                     hAxes = gca;
      hAxes_pos = get(hAxes,'Position');
      disp(hAxes_pos);                                                             for nodeIndex = 1:s_mobility.NB_NODES
      hAxes = axes('Position',hAxes_pos);
      vh_node_pos(nodeIndex) =        plot(vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x(1),vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y(1),'*','color',[0.3 0.3 1]);
      set(hAxes,'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color','none',...
           'XTickLabel',[]);
       end                    But I could put only 1 plot. Please suggest and help me.